# Update Table Using Laravel Model

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

I've got a table for a sports team. The record shows the team selection and some other information. I want to update the record with the team selection. My model is thus:

```
class Selection extends Model {

protected $table = "selection";

protected $fillable = [
    'loose',
    'hooker',
    'tight',
    'secrow1',
    'secrow2',
    'blindflank',
    'openflank',
    'eight',
    'scrum',
    'fly',
    'leftwing',
    'rightwing',
    'fullback',
    'sub1',
    'sub2',
    'sub3',
    'sub4',
    'sub5'
];
```

}

So I have a form which gives all the data for the positions and gives the id for the record in the DB. In my controller, I've got:

```
public function storeFirstTeam()
{
    $input = Request::all();

    Selection::update($input->id,$input);

    return redirect('first-team');
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::update() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Can anyone point out my silly error?

Comment: You have to first select the row you want to update. How would you get the `id` of the selection when you post the update request?

Comment: Try Something like this: `Selection::whereId($id)->update($request->except(['_method','_token']));`

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Please check the code below and this would solve your problem:

```
Selection::whereId($id)->update($request->all());
```

Comment: Does this method `update()` get `rollBack`if something goes wrong? If it's between a `DB::beginTransaction()`

Comment: The request can contain some custom fields, from form e.g. I put  array like this:`Foydabaranda::whereId($request->id_eslox)->update([
                   'login' => $request->login_eslox,
                   'parol' => $request->parol_eslox,
                   'tuKiTu' => $request->xeli_tochka,
               ]);` Also works as I wanted.

Answer (score 13):

The error message tells you everything you know: you’re trying to call a method statically (using the double colons) that isn’t meant to be.

The `update()` method is meant to be called on a model *instance*, so first you need to retrieve one:

```
$selection = Selection::find($id);
```

You can then can the `update()` method on that:

```
$selection->update($request->all());
```

Answer (score 7):

You should write it like given example below:

```
Selection::where('id', $input['id'])->update($input);
// Or use this using dynamic where
Selection::whereId($input['id'])->update($input);
```

Alternatively, you may write it like this as well:

```
Selection::find($input['id'])->fill($input)->save();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also simply update the fields manually:

```php
Selection::whereId($id)->update($request->all());
```

Comment: Please avoid code only responses. view https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer  for more information

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to update with primary key but in my case I dont have id field in the detail table. To do it just run a query like this:

```
DB::table("shop_menu_detail")
    ->where(['name' => 'old name', 'language' => 'english'])
    ->update(['name' => 'new name']);
```

where is used as it is.